# Opening a websocket connection in R to Binance

Tags: r, api, websocket

I can't find a way to make a websocket connection in R.

It seems as if all of the libraries for websockets in R are depreciated.

Has anyone found a way to make a websocket connection to Binance?

https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html#kline-wss-endpoint

Comment: https://github.com/ropenscilabs/webrockets

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(websocket)

websocket::WebSocket$new("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bctusdt@trade")
```

See https://github.com/rstudio/websocket for more

Comment: And how to use it?
Can you give a working example with getting some data please